# Windows Service going to Idle state

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, service, windows-services

I have a windows service that communicates with a DB residing on a different server.The service is installed and always running.The service will look out if there any new records in the DB Table and get 1000 records at a time via stored proc and process records (updates/creates in the CRM system).
Logic is working perfectly alright but the problem is with service going to idle state(service is in running state but won't execute the method 'ProcessNewOtranRecords' that calls stored proc) after few hours. When the service is restarted it again works as expected for few more hours.

Please suggest me if there is any good approach to keep service active all the time.

Here is the code :

```
    using Microsoft.Win32;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Security.Permissions; 
    using System.ServiceProcess;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using CRM.Objects.BusinessLogic; 

    namespace CRM
    {
      partial class CrmProcessOtran : ServiceBase
    {
        OtranBL _otranBL = new OtranBL();
        private System.Timers.Timer mainTimer;
        int eventID = 0;

        public CrmProcessOtran()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Service Start");

            mainTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(30000); // 30 seconds
            mainTimer.Elapsed += PerformOtranOperations;
            mainTimer.AutoReset = false;
            mainTimer.Start(); 
        }


        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Service Stopped");

            mainTimer.Stop();
            mainTimer.Dispose();
            mainTimer = null; 
        }

        public void PerformOtranOperations(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            eventID++; 
            eventLog1.WriteEntry(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss") + " - checking for new otran records", EventLogEntryType.Information, eventID);
            // Check for new otran records 
            int otranRecords = _otranBL.GetOtranRecordCount(eventLog1);
            if (otranRecords == 0)
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry("0 new otran records", EventLogEntryType.Information, eventID);
                return;
            }

            eventLog1.WriteEntry(otranRecords.ToString("N0") + " new otran records found with proc_status = 0", EventLogEntryType.Information, eventID);
            // Process new records 
            eventLog1.WriteEntry(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss") + " - Begin processing new otran records", EventLogEntryType.Information, eventID);
            int processedrecords = _otranBL.ProcessNewOtranRecords(eventLog1);
            eventLog1.WriteEntry(processedrecords.ToString() + " processed records", EventLogEntryType.Information, eventID);

            mainTimer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "idle" exactly?

Comment: What does _"service going to idle state"_ mean? Does it crash with an exception recorded in the event log?

Comment: Windows Services don't have an "idle state" unless you explicitly coded that into your application.

Comment: edited the post. Idle in my case is the service shows as running in the windows services section but won't execute the code.This happens only after few hours.

Comment: I suppose your problem is inside `PerformOtranOperations`.
If you needs to execute operation every 30 seconds, you don't have to call `Start` method every time the callback method is fired.

Comment: I want to execute ProcessNewOtranRecords only after successfully processing the initial 1000 records. so even in this case, you think i will not have to call start method ??

Answer (score 0):

You should add some Try/Catch/Finally logic into PerformOtranOperations. You're propably experiencing some exception after some iterations and your `mainTimer.Start();` is never called from that moment.

So the service is running but the trigger is not active any more.

Answer (score 0):

The Timer component catches and suppresses all exceptions thrown by event handlers 
for the Elapsed event; see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Because of this you probably don't see any errors in the Windows event viewer.

Can you rework your code to use a System.Threading.Timer instance instead, which doesn't swallow the exception if something goes wrong.

As Pavlinll suggest, you should implement some error handling in order to keep your service running.